# Calling a path in java method

Tags: java, variables, path, environment

I have a small problem calling a path(that has the python file, that I need to run) in the following code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs,env,
                    new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\Balkishore\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testinstrument_Rest\\build\\web"));//excuting python file
```

As it can be seen from the above code, the python file is called using the path specified in java.io.file function. But it is very specific, as it can be run only in my computer. How can i make it generic, so that it is possible to run this piece of code in any computer?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this file is already exist in the app then you need to do

```
ServletContext.getRealPath("/");
```

which will give you the path to web root now from here you need to move relatively to reach to your file

---

If this is an external file

put it in `${user.home}/appname/`

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"APP_NAME"
```

and instruct your users to put the file in this path, or read the path from some configuration file (.properties, .conf)

Comment: First of all thak you veyr much for replying. But i am really sorry i am not following you. I am very much new to java. Could you please explain it to me. I have this file in my web folder in my netbeans project. This is not an external file.

Comment: how can i use servletContext in my source code?  Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanx a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your python script to the location relative to your working directory and use relative path. Alternatively use configuration file or property to read the path from.

Comment: how can i use proerty or configuration file to do so? Any help would be very much appreciated. And thanks a ton for replying.